# How do I position divs into 3 columns, reposition into 2 when on narrow screen

Tags: css, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Yes, I do realise the title of this question is poor. Feel free to improve it.

I'm trying to build CSS for a page which has the following requirements.

- There are six 'boxes'.
- Each pair of boxes has equal total height
- the middle pair (boxes 3 and 4) have equal height
- they should be arranged as on the below mockup, in three columns on a wide screen
- they should be arranged as on the second mockup below, in two columns
- on the very narrow screen they should be arranged all in a single column
- there should be no gap between a box and the one directly below/above it
- I was trying to get it done using Twitter Bootstrap but it's not a requirement
- I'd prefer a 100% CSS solution over a CSS+JQuery/other JS solution
- it's for a corporate website so sadly, has to work in IE8+ (IE7 would be nice too, although not a must if we can have a reasonable fallback)

[image: the layout on wide page]
[image: the layout on narrow page]

Here's a jsFiddle for you to play with: http://goo.gl/o2YoY

Comment: consider to post any code snipet. http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: fair point. I built a "demo" version of my current (pathetic) progress and put it on jsfiddle

Comment: Must it be in that order or change the order of box is acceptable?

Comment: It must end up being same total height for both columns. @invisal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `column-count` and media queries:

```
.inner{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#outer{
    column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
      #outer{
        column-count:2;
        -webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    }
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
      #outer{
        column-count:1;
        -webkit-column-count:1; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -moz-column-count: 1; /* Firefox */
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6wWDX/1/

Browser compatibility of `column-count`: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: that's an interesting take. I didn't know of `column-count`. I shall investigate...

Comment: I updated the fiddle to account for other requirement I've got (varying height and the fact there has to be no gap) http://jsfiddle.net/ycaZJ/1/ works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and IE10. Sadly, I have to support older IE versions too, any way of getting it working there?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  You could have a js fallback.